# How to add an array of xml files in my existing single file script?

Tags: php, dom

The following code gets the fan_count of the file and shows it. What I want to do is to create an array that can hold many urls and echo each one the fan_count.

How can I modify the code ? Thank you

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile ('domain.com/xmlfile.xml');

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$posts = $xPath->query('//page');

foreach($posts as $post) {

$fans = $post->getElementsByTagName( "fan_count" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $fans;

}

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the XML feed only contains a number? If it did, it would not be a valid XML document I believe. Are you viewing the raw output?

Comment: I have updated it with the xml

Comment: You need to use XML reading tools like SimpleXML for this. The reason you are seeing only number when you echo the report is because the browser (not php) filters the tags out. The content however, does contain all of the tags.

Comment: "Updated" what? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Thank you Dani. @downvoter Is a down vote the best solution to a as I wrote "beginner" ? I am new, learning the rules and updated my question twice.

Comment: You need to parse the XML... try using SimpleXML

Comment: @Sampas You should read http://stackoverflow.com/faq before asking a question. Your first version of question indicated that you were reading numbers but actually you are reading an XML (RSS) file. Look at the three answers below, nobody understood your question correctly because your question was not clear enough.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I am trying to do now...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$feeds = array(
'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=1234567',
'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=7564321'
);

foreach ($feeds as $feed) {


$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

    $fans_numbers = $xml->xpath("//fan_count");
    foreach ($fans_numbers as $elem){
       print_r($elem);
    }

}
```

Comment: It returned me Array () I have put it below the `$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);` until `}`

Comment: I edited the code to include yours too - In the first place I have only written the lines you have to use to access the `fan_count` element from the XML

Comment: Again I get the same result. I edited your answer with real IDs, I did mine also.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = $sum.$contents
```

is this ok?